# Separate submit buttons on forms which tell form "action" to post to different files?

Tags: php, html, forms, action

I have included an additional Submit button within my form which I am going to use like so.

1. User selects item
2. User hits **"Add another item" Submit button** on form.
3. Form POSTS to itself and reloads the page so user can add another item
4. Once user has added several items the user hits **"Finished" Submit button.**
5. The form posts to another file with all the accumulated items.

I have a uneasy feeling that this might not be achievable with PHP/HTML alone and that I might have to use some Javascript to modify the form action before the form starts to POST data?

Thoughts and ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to modify the form based on which button is clicked, or you can check server side (i.e. using PHP) which button was clicked and act accordingly.

A submit-button is a form-input just like any other, i.e. you can give it a name and a value, which you can check for server side.

On client side (i.e. using JavaScript) you would bind a handler to the button's click-event, modify the form's action-attribute and submit it to the new address.

Here's a client side example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form submit test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="baz.html" method="post">
            <input id="bar" type="submit" class="button" value="bar.html" name="" />
            <input id="foo" type="submit" class="button" value="foo.html" name="" />
        </form>

        <script>
            // Find the two buttons from the DOM and assign them to separate variables
            var barBtn = document.getElementById('bar'),
                fooBtn = document.getElementById('foo');

            // Click-handler for the buttons. 
            // NB! For this code to work as intended, it needs to run 
            // in the context of the button, otherwise, the this-keyword 
            // will not resolve correctly and this will result in an error
            // NB2! This code also requires that a button's value will be
            // the desired action handler. Usually you would probably not
            // do this, but use the button's name/value to lookup the 
            // correct form action.
            function modifyAction(e) {
                this.form.action = this.value;
            }

            // Bind an event handler to an object
            // NB! This is not code you should use in production
            function bindEvent(target, event, callback) {
                if (target.addEventListener) {
                    target.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
                } else if (target.attachEvent) {
                    target.attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
                }
            }

            // Delegate creates a wrapping closure which binds the 
            // original function's context to an object, i.e. ensuring
            // the this-keyword always refers to the same object when
            // the returned function is invoked. 
            function delegate(context, method) {
                return function () {
                    return method.apply(context, arguments);
                }
            }

            // Bind the click-event of the barBtb, and handle it
            // with the modifyAction-function bound to the barBtn.
            // I.e. run the modifyAction function, with the this-keyword
            // bound to barBtn
            bindEvent(barBtn, 'click', delegate(barBtn, modifyAction));

            // Same as above for fooBtn
            bindEvent(fooBtn, 'click', delegate(fooBtn, modifyAction));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just for sake of completeness, here's a jQuery-example of the same:

```
<form action="baz.html" method="post">
    <input id="bar" type="submit" class="button" value="bar.html" name="" />
    <input id="foo" type="submit" class="button" value="foo.html" name="" />
</form>

<script>
// Jquery event-handlers are automatically bound to
// the element selected, so using "this" is safe
function modifyAction(e) {
    this.form.action = this.value;
}

// Bind the click-event on all input with type=submit
$("input[type=submit]").click(modifyAction);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I need the new Submit button to POST to two different pages. If I have the form POST to just one page and then check the value. I will lose the POST data when the script redirects to appropriate page?

Comment: On a redirect, you will lose the POST data, yes, but leveraging PHP:s `include` enables you to bring the code in where and when you need it and afterwards you can redirect accordingly.

Comment: Hi @nikc , any chance you could link me to some info to explain the Javascript code. I understand the bit at the start assigning two variables for each submit button. However the rest I do not understand

Comment: @loosebruce: I can add some explanations to the example code. In production, however, I believe you will be better off relying on a cross browser tested solution, i.e. using a library, such as jQuery, Underscore.js, Mootools etc.

Answer (score 3):

Give the two submit buttons the same names but different values.  You can check the value in your php file.

Example

```
<form action="something.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="one">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="two">
</form>
```

**something.php**

```
switch( $_POST['submit'] ) {
    case 'one':
    case 'two':
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this without javascript. Just give your submit button names with different values:

```
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="addItem">Add item</button>
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="finish">Finished</button>
```

Now inside the script you are posting the form to you can determine which button was clicked by examining the `$_POST['btn']` value and take the respective actions.

Comment: Thanks, this way I would need to redirect then to the appropriate page. However this would mean I would lose my POST data if it jumps to another PHP page?

Comment: @loosebruce, yes, if you redirect you will loose the POST data. You should not redirect. You could redirect only once all the processing is done at the end in order to show some success message.

Comment: thanks but the form I am trying to make is like a shopping basket in which you can select one thing. If you want to add more things you would click on a specific Submit button. This button would cause the same page to reload but with the data added to the shopping basket. This allows you to add more and more items. Until you click the "Finish" submit button in which it will go to another page where you will pay for the Total items. 

Sorry if I did not explain it clearly.

Comment: @loosebruce, no, your description was very clear. It's just that if you don't want to use javascript that's your only way to implement it.