# Rails, 1 form, two buttons. Search and New

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I think I'm trying to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559385/separate-submit-buttons-on-forms-which-tell-form-action-to-post-to-different-f) but in rails. I would like to have a search form of sorts, but instead of two separate forms I want to use one text input and have two submit buttons, one which initiates a search and the other begins creating a new work order using the parameter from the form. I have already implemented the second half, but can't seem to find an obvious way to do it. This [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form) seems to start to get at what I want, but it seems like the rails helpers are getting in the way more than anything. Is there any way to do this without javascript? Also it seems like I'm mixing raw html with rails erb, so I suspect that can be improved as well. Unless it turns out rails simply can't do what I want then does that mean I need to resort to straight up HTML or even javascript? My only hesitation to use javascript/jquery is that I am currently very weak with them and wouldn't even know where to put the js files or what to name them.

```
<%= form_tag new_work_order_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form navbar-left" do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :client_number, params[:client_number],  class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter client number"%>
  </div>
  <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-default">New Work Order</button>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you use javascript/jquery?

Comment: I can, albeit ham-fisted and clumsily. It was actually my first impulse but I don't know where the js would "go" so to speak.

Comment: using rails, you have the `app/assets/javascripts/` folder. you'd want to make a new file, add the javascript to bind an ajax call to the non-submitting button in this file, and then be sure to require it in the manifest.

Comment: You can have two submit buttons, both could route to the same controller action, and you can handle it on the controller, with params[:commit],you can  use submit_tag

Comment: @PhilVarg does it need to be named anything in particular? Like that excerpt comes from app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb. And as a follow up would jquery to make a table "do stuff" that's in app/views/work_orders/schedule.html.erb have to have a corresponding name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each button a value attribute.

```
 <%= form_tag new_work_order_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form navbar-left" do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :client_number, params[:client_number],  class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter client number"%>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="new">
    New Work Order
  </button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="search">
    Search
  </button>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller method check the params[:commit]:

```
if params[:commit] == "new"
  # create the new WorkOrder
else
  # do the search for existing WorkOrders
end
```

You may want to use a different controller method name since it will be handling both search and new instead of just new.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two different actions for every method(new and search), this for REST good practices. 
And for this, you could use other rails form way and set the action for every button like `<%= button_to 'Call Action', action_path, method: [POST|GET]%>`